# How to select Date,ID ,Qty at the maximum month of Date of each ID

Tags: sql-server

I have..

```
Date         ID   Qty
2019/4/1     A    11  
2019/5/1     A    22  
2019/6/1     A    33 'need (Maximum Month of A)
2019/6/2     A    44 'need (Maximum Month of A)
2019/7/1     B    55 'need (Maximum Month of B)
2019/7/2     B    66 'need (Maximum Month of B)
2019/6/1     B    77
2019/5/1     B    88
```

I need all rows at maximum month of Date for each ID as below

```
Date         ID   Qty  
2019/6/1     A    33
2019/6/2     A    44
2019/7/1     B    55
2019/7/2     B    66
```

Comment: I really don't understand how you are arriving at that output in any way.  Can you please explain your logic some more?

Comment: The result doesn't match the (unclear) description, and posting unsorted data doesn't help either. Are you looking for the *ID* that has the largest quantity per month? In that case, why are there *two* rows of June in the results?

Comment: And why isn't `2019/6/1     B    77` in the results?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited the Question. Please see again.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that row is not maximum month of ID B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution:

```
WITH RankedTable AS(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, "Date") DESC) AS RankMonth
    FROM @Table
)

SELECT "Date", ID, Qty
FROM RankedTable
WHERE RankMonth = 1
```

And if you want max over year and month:

```
WITH RankedTable AS(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, "Date") DESC, DATEPART(MONTH, "Date") DESC) AS RankYearMonth
    FROM @Table
)

SELECT "Date", ID, Qty
FROM RankedTable
WHERE RankYearMonth = 1
```

Comment: i will be test on Monday,Thank you.

Comment: it works. thank you.